# WSO2SP as analytics for APIM and EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to use WSO2SP-4.3.0 as analytics for both WSO2AM-2.6.0 and WSO2EI-6.4.0 (integrator). The only reference I found for this options is mentioned here https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Analytics+Solutions

Setting up ports and solutions map:

```
analytics.solutions:
  APIM-analytics.enabled: true
  EI-analytics.enabled: true
```

running a worker and dashboard of the SP

Seems the stream definitions for loganalyzer is not loaded, worker throws following exceptions:

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} - Dropping wrongly formatted event sent 
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting loganalyzer:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
     ...
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException:
 No StreamDefinition for streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 present in cache
      ...
    ...
```

I haven't find source of the  *loganalyzer* stream definition (even in the original ws2am-analytics-2.6.0 package).

Any help is appreciated (or shall I just disable the DAS_AGENT from APIM)?

Comment: Please check whether you have older AM version pointed at the new SP based analytics distribution since log_analyzer is discontinued in the lates version

Comment: @Tishan thanks for the update, I won't use the loganalyzer then (DAS_AGENT logger). Indeed events form APIM and EI are processed (though EI:ESB stats are not shown, maybe I open another question for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a configuration issue. It might be easier to try one at a time to narrow down the problem. I suggest you follow [[EI-Analytics] Configure WSO2 SP for WSO2 EI](https://medium.com/@isharailanga/configure-wso2-sp-for-wso2-ei-for-ei-analytics-8e7d8ef128fe) to configure EI analytics with SP with enabling EI analytics first.

Comment: it' all look working, just the portal doesn't show any data (when using analytics bundled along wso2ei it's working all, I don't much understand where is the difference)

Comment: Gusto2, Did you configure the data source in dashboard profile (/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml) pointing to the correct database?

Comment: @Niveathika: yeah,I had to use an external database to make it work (I used mysql , using the default h2 did not work properly).  Still some tables are not created for micro-gw analytics (we don't use mgw, so it's fine so far)

Comment: @gusto2 After populating the database with EI analytics data, can you verify whether tables contain populated data by examining DB tables?

Comment: @TharinduBandara Definitely there are data frmom API GW (default gateway) and EI, we didn't use micro-gateway so far

Comment: @gusto2 Since this seems like an issue with the portal, we can check with browser console whether there are any error messages. For EI, this usually happens if stats may not be enabled or with a data source pointing issue. Can you check with the browser console?